# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr<DataModel>', is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    Future<DataModel> submitData(
    int id,
    String user,
    String userId,
    String title,
    String description,
    String location,
    String jobType,
    int category,
    String salary,
    String companyName,
    String url,
    DateTime lastDate,
    bool isPublished,
    bool isClosed,
    DateTime timestamp) async {
 var response = await http.post(Uri.https('jobspace-isnp.herokuapp.com', 'api/jobs'), 
    body: {
    "id": id,
    "user": user,
    "user_id": userId,
    "title": title,
    "description": description,
    "location": location,
    "job_type": jobType,
    "category": category,
    "salary": salary,
    "company_name": companyName,
    "url": url,
    "last_date": lastDate,
    "is_published": isPublished,
    "is_closed": isClosed,
   });
  var data = response.body;
  print(data);

  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    String responseString = response.body;
    dataModelFromJson(responseString);
  } else
    return null;
}
```

I am getting this error: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

How can I solve it?

Comment: this is because you are not returning anything from your `async` method - you have to return `DataModel`

Answer (score 0):

Using null safety in your code, can `submitData` function return null value. to do that just add `?` after `DataModel` so your code will be like this

```
  Future<DataModel?> submitData(
    int id,
    String user,
    String userId,
    String title,
    String description,
    String location,
    String jobType,
    int category,
    String salary,
    String companyName,
    String url,
    DateTime lastDate,
    bool isPublished,
    bool isClosed,
    DateTime timestamp) async {
 var response = await http.post(Uri.https('jobspace-isnp.herokuapp.com', 'api/jobs'), 
    body: {
    "id": id,
    "user": user,
    "user_id": userId,
    "title": title,
    "description": description,
    "location": location,
    "job_type": jobType,
    "category": category,
    "salary": salary,
    "company_name": companyName,
    "url": url,
    "last_date": lastDate,
    "is_published": isPublished,
    "is_closed": isClosed,
   });
  var data = response.body;
  print(data);

  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    String responseString = response.body;
    dataModelFromJson(responseString);
  } else
    return null;
}
```

read more about [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)